# how to include an icon image in AddFolderIcon() of installshield

Tags: installshield

Where I need to mention the icon 'XX.ico' path in the below method.
Right now a icon is created on desktop with some image(XY.ico) corresponding to folder icon
Now I need to change that image(XY.ico). New image icon has to be place for the same folder icon.

AddFolderIcon (szProgramFolder, szItemName, szCommandLine,
szWorkingDir,
szIconPath, nIcon, szShortCutKey, REPLACE)

Answer (score 3):

If I follow the question, the szIconPath argument is where you'll want to point to your icon file.